# calculate limit with Taylor and L'hopital

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

i need to calculate a limit, and our teacher told us to use L'hopital and Taylor aproximations.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left({\sin(x)\over x}\right)^{1/x^2}$$

and that must be equal to;

$$e^{1/6}$$

and i tried some things but i can't get to the answer, a little help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the limit be $L$. Then

\begin{align}\log L &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \log\left(\frac{x + (1/6)x^3 + O(x^5)}{x}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{6}x^2 + O(x^4)\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{6}x^2 + O(x^4)\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{6} + O(x^2)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{6}
\end{align}

Therefore $L = e^{1/6}$.

Comment: What is $O\left(x\right)$? I would like to go look it up...

Comment: We say that $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to a$ if there exists an $M > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M|g(x)|$ whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$.

Comment: oooh ok ok i think i get it now, thanks for the reply!